# Не - слитно или раздельно: "неопределённо, но не насмешливо"

Tags: грамматика

> Выражение этого взора было очень *неопределённо*, но ***не*** насмешливо... ([Лермонтов](https://books.google.ru/books?id=aAFUVwju4csC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=sn1p8g_uLx&sig=zIrvUeO4cTsYqR1zcG_lGZWTuns&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F-C2VOP_L-LNygORjIG4Bg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), абзац со словами "Хорошенькая княжна...")

Союз **но** здесь имеет значение союза **и** -- это не противопоставление. *Насмешливо* здесь *краткое прилагательное*, а не наречие. Да даже если и наречие, значит *неопределённо* тоже наречие, но **не** с ним написано слитно.

Почему с первым словом **не** написано слитно, а со вторым раздельно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оба слова (неопределённо и насмешливо) - краткие прилагательные. 
На сайте [Gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=def&text=19_24) приводится следующее правило:

> § 89. Не пишется раздельно:
>   ...
>   3. При существительных, прилагательных и наречиях, если есть или подразумевается противопоставление, например: не удача привела нас к успеху, а выдержка и хладнокровие; не смерть страшна – страшна твоя немилость (Пушкин); утро настало не ясное, а туманное; поезд идет не быстро и не медленно (подразумевается: «с какой-то средней скоростью»); не завтра (здесь не может не быть противопоставления).

Таким образом, выражение её взора было неопределённо (нет противопоставления), но (хотя бы) не насмешливо (противопоставляется "насмешливо").